# IntelliJ Build Configuration keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows, keyboard, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm kind of insane about not using the mouse. How do I get from the following starting location to the ending location. See screenshot![image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible at the moment, created a new issue, [please vote](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-96424).

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it does not appear to be possible.  Here is a link for keyboard shortcuts in IntelliJ:

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Keyboard_Shortcuts.html